# Move / disable legacy icon bar from bottom left in GNOME 3.16

Tags: gnome3, fedora-22

Fedora 22 (GNOME 3.16) introduced this expandable legacy icon bar in the bottom-left corner of the screen:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, even when closed it takes up a few valuable pixels in the corner (where I am usually looking, when using a terminal). It also annoyingly expands whenever my mouse cursor ends up on top of it.

How do we move or disable this thing?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try the GNOME shell extension [TopIcons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/). This moves the legacy tray icons shown in this bar to the main GNOME bar, up in the top right by the menu.

[image: screenshot in action]

Comment: This should actually be the standard. Hot corners and sides are the worst!

Comment: It worked eventually for me. Thanks! Note for others: (1) pop ups should not be blocked, (2) (for proxied Internet) downloads of the extension should also be allowed, (3) re-login/re-start of Gnome is not required - it should just work, (4) if Chrome fails, try Firefox.

Comment: @uvsmtid If you struggle installing gnome-shell extensions with Chrome, take a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/269788/157373) Chrome Extension/native package combo.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is the shell extension [Hide Legacy Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/967/hide-legacy-tray/), which will simply hide the system tray altogether.